# Возможна ли постановка тире в данном случае?

Tags: запятые

### В выходные или на выходных – какой вариант выберете вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В выходные или на выходных – какой вариант выберете вы?**

Постановка тире в данном случае обязательна.

Это изолированный номинатив в препозиции, выраженный однородным рядом. Номинатив называет две падежные формы, относительно  которых делается выбор.

Именительный изолированный подкрепляется местоимением и **в построениях с вопросительным предложением.** Смысл вопроса в таких случаях целиком связан с понятием, обозначенным номинативом. Например: Разум на других планетах – каков он? (газ.).

https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/